# How do I implement bold/italic/ wordpad-like features in js?

Tags: javascript, html

[here's the reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhD30.png)

I am trying to make a simple blog, and I've got the backend and database parts down. I have two fields- one for the title and the other for the description.
Currently, I'm saving these in a table without any markup. I think storing titles without any markup is okay as I can always render them in h2 tags when fetching from the database into the frontend.
The problem is- I want to implement bold/italic/hyperlink-like features and I don't how to do it. I am not looking for code- I will do that on my own- just the approach I should take. I think I could change the textarea's content on button click and that should work.
Should I be saving the HTML markup into the sql table or is there a better way? Thanks in advance :)

Here's rough example of what I will be doing if it helps.

```
boldButton.addEventListener( 
 'click',
 () => {
  textArea.value = '<b>'+ textArea.value + '</b>';
}
)
```

Comment: A simple approach would be to store the bold / italic states in variables e.g. `isBold` and `isItalic` then update those on button click.

Comment: You can use tinymce or summernote like plugins.

Comment: @T.Shah I am new to this idea of using plugins- and I did take a look at tinymce a while ago. I think I like the suneditor one more. (In suneditor) Is it possible to get the HTML Content of the textarea so I can send it to the database? 
Thanks guys :)

Comment: Yes. You can save html content from editor in database.  Whichever plugin you choose, there are examples and docs to explain all.